# ftp_put sends incomplete file

Tags: php, ftp

i have to put an xml file to a remote server, using php.

my file is created by a php script (and everything is ok), then i upload it to another server.
but when it goes there, the file is incomplete! lasts 10 lines are stripped out.

any help?

**PHP CODE**

```
function upload(){  
    $ftp = ftp_connect('ftp.myhost.com');  
    $rc  = ftp_login($ftp, 'myuser', 'mypwd');  
    $rc  = ftp_pasv ($ftp, FALSE);  
    $rc  = ftp_chdir($ftp, $folder);  
    $rc  = ftp_put  ($ftp, 'myfile.xml', 'myfile.xml', FTP_ASCII);  
    ftp_close($ftp);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using 'FTP_BINARY' instead of 'FTP_ASCII'?

Also, I don't think its what is causing your problem but where does the $folder variable get populated in your code?

Comment: yep, everything is ok in the code, that's the weird thing -.-

Answer (score 1):

HI,

User FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII
check for the filesize also, may be possible that your server does not allow heavy files

Comment: tried with FTP_BINARY, but i still get the problem. also the file is very small, 40k